# Gradient of the loss of DistilBERT for measuring token importance

Tags: pytorch, transformer-model, attention-model, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model

I am trying to access the gradient of the loss in DistilBERT with respect to each attention weight in the first layer. I could access the computed gradient value of the output weight matrix via the following code when `requires_grad=True`

```
loss.backward()
for name, param in model.named_parameters():
    if name == 'transformer.layer.0.attention.out_lin.weight':
       print(param.grad)  #shape is [768,768]
```

where `model` is the loaded distilbert model.
My question is how to get the gradient with respect to [SEP] or [CLS] or other tokens' attention? I need it to reproduce the figure about the "Gradient-based feature importance estimates for attention to [SEP]" in the following link: 
https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/explainability-of-bert-through-attention-7dbbab8a7062

A similar question for the same purpose has been asked in the following, but it is not my issue:
[BERT token importance measuring issue. Grad is none](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61286574/bert-token-importance-measuring-issue-grad-is-none)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the gradients are retained only for parameters, basically just to save memory. If you need gradients of inner nodes of the computation graph, you need to have the respective tensor before calling `backward()` and add a hook that will be executed at the backward pass.

A minimum solution from [PyTorch forum](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/why-cant-i-see-grad-of-an-intermediate-variable/94/3):

```py
yGrad = torch.zeros(1,1)
def extract(xVar):
    global yGrad
    yGrad = xVar    

xx = Variable(torch.randn(1,1), requires_grad=True)
yy = 3*xx
zz = yy**2

yy.register_hook(extract)

#### Run the backprop:
print (yGrad) # Shows 0.
zz.backward()
print (yGrad) # Show the correct dzdy
```

In this case, the gradients are stored in a global variable where they persist after PyTorch get rid of them in the graph itself.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. Now I see how to save the gradient of intermediate nodes. Another question would be that each layer in DistilBERT calls an instance of ``MultiHeadSelfAttention'' class to compute the attention weights locally. The only place to call register_hook() is therefore inside the forward() of the class where weights are computed. If we assume our DistilBERT model has 6 layers, then register_hook() is called 6 times. yGrad in this case would be a list to save the gradient of weights of all layers. Is it correct to repeatedly call register_hook() inside the forward()? thanks

Comment: Yes, then just `yGrad` a list a append to the list in the hook.

Comment: Thanks, a quick question: if I use list to keep the gradients of each layer, does it append in the same order as the layers go from 1 to 6, or because of the backward gradient computations it keeps the gradient values in reverse order, i.e., layer 6 as the first element in the list and layer 1 as the last element?

Comment: It will be in the reserved order.